# Non-diagonal elements of the Schwarzchild metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor

The Schwarzchild metric is the most general spherically symmetric, vacuum solution of the Einstein field equations.

I was wondering if there was a simple argument to explain why the Schwarzchild metric is diagonal in the spherical coordinate system, i.e. of the form

$$ds^2 = dt^2 + \cdots d\theta^2 + \cdots d\phi^2 + \cdots dr^2.$$

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_Schwarzschild_solution) Wikipedia article gives a really simple explanation which seems false.

(When you write the transformation law for $ g_{\mu 4} $, it should be understood:
$$ g'_{\mu 4} (x') = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^4}g_{\alpha\beta}(x)= -g_{\mu 4}(x) ,$$ while at the same time the invariance tells you that $$ g'_{\mu 4}(x') = g_{\mu 4}(x') .$$ This leads to the conclusion that $$ g_{\mu 4}(x') = -g_{\mu 4}(x) ,$$ but I fail to see how to go further in the reasoning without any aditionnal assumption.)

Other derivations either start from the diagonal form or are much more complicated.

It's probably a dumb question, but I fail to see a simple argument.

Comment: I'm ok with the general transformation law part, but there's no reason to say that $g_{\mu,\nu}$ is invariant under those symmetries.

Comment: - I was wondering if there was a simple argument to explain why the Schwarzchild metric is diagonal in the spherical coordinate system - I may be missing something here, but isn't the fact that it *just is* diagonal an explanation in itself? And about spherical coordinates: it is rather due to the fact that the metric is of this particularly simple form in these coordinates that we call them spherical, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

OP is right: For a generic pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M;g)$, there does not necessarily exist an open coordinate neighborhoods $U\subseteq M$, where the metric $g_{|U}$ is on diagonal form. [Fermi normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates) always ensure a diagonal form along a geodesic $\gamma$ (but not necessarily in the ambient spacetime outside the geodesic). However, the Schwarzschild geometry has [Killing symmetries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) that ensure that diagonal metrics exist in open neighborhoods.